# Should I call or email to ask for a job?

Tags: interviewing, internship, networking

I interned this past semester at a company I fell in love with. I worked hard and was able to work on a diverse range of projects with multiple teams in the organization. Near my last day I was at a company holiday party and one senior employee I had met before pulled me aside to ask about my plans/interest in returning to the company. I expressed to him my keen interest in working there and he told me to give him a call when I'm almost done with school and ready for my next move.

This is in fact my last semester of school so I was thinking about strategies for making something happen to get back in at the company.

This employee who told me to call him seemed pretty earnest about it but it can be hard to tell sometimes whether someone's making a real offer or saying it as an empty courtesy.

Should I actually call or would an email be more appropriate? I know I'm probably overthinking this but I'm curious...

Answer (score 5):

Email first asking for a good time for a call to get more information, and take it from there.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

> I expressed to him my keen interest in working there and he told me to
>   *give him a call* when I'm almost done with school and ready for my next
>   move.

Seems like your answer was already given to you specifically and directly.

Just give him a call.

Comment: @Tom Maxwell ...What Joe said...